# Tomcat/Hibernate connection to MySql fails with "Communications link failure" & "Permission denied"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, tomcat7, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to connect to MySql (=MariaDB) on the localhost (lets call it A) from a tomcat webapp using Hibernate, but keep getting Communication link failure (the full exception trace attached below).

I have another replica of the DB on a different machine (lets call it B) and also using a 3rd computer for development (lets call it C).

1) I have no issues connecting from C to either of the DBs (A & B). 
2) On "A" I have no problems connecting locally to the DB (running 'mysql -u' command). I also have no problems doing telnet on port 3306 to either A or B. so I assume both DBs are up and running and available for connections.

The only problem is when I'm trying to connect from the production tomcat (running on A) to either A or B db. I get the error:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

From similar cases of this error, I saw the majority of errors were due to invalid user/pass credentials or illegal IPs. I also tried to change the ip to localhost , 127.0.0.1 and 10.90.41.155 (which is the actual ip of the machine). Nothing helps, and also keep in mind that connection only fails from the specific tomcat installation on A.

I also tried the following:
1) Added "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" to catalina startup
2) Tried to connect to illegal addresses/ports - this changed (as expected) the final error from "permission denied" into "no route to host".
3) Added the following to my connection string: "autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&characterEncoding=utf-8" - this resulted in the same error ("Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up." + "Permission denied (connect failed)"
4) Tried both DB urls. for the local DB tried with localhost, 127.0.0.1 and the actual ip. tried both with and without  ":3306" in the connection string

Attached is the  hibernate.cfg file +full server trace of the exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://10.90.41.151/boonder
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
   XXXXXXXXXX
   </property>

   <!-- List of XML mapping files      -->
   <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/>
   <mapping resource="Issue.hbm.xml"/>
   <mapping resource="TraderIssue.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Exception is:

```
        type Exception report

        message Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

        description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

        exception

        org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.<init>(DataSingleton.java:54)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.instance(DataSingleton.java:74)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.loginInner(LoginCtrl.java:62)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.login(LoginCtrl.java:41)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
            org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
            org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
            org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
            org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
            org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
            org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.<init>(DataSingleton.java:48)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.instance(DataSingleton.java:74)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.loginInner(LoginCtrl.java:62)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.login(LoginCtrl.java:41)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
            org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    ...
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.<init>(DataSingleton.java:48)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.instance(DataSingleton.java:74)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.loginInner(LoginCtrl.java:62)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.login(LoginCtrl.java:41)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

        The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:166)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:58)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:853)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:440)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)

    ...

    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
            org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
            org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
            org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
            org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
            org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.<init>(DataSingleton.java:48)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.instance(DataSingleton.java:74)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.loginInner(LoginCtrl.java:62)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.login(LoginCtrl.java:41)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

        The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
            sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
            com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
            com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133)
            com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
            com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:83)
            com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:204)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:975)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:843)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:440)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
            org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
            org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
            org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
            org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
            org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
            org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
            org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.<init>(DataSingleton.java:48)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.instance(DataSingleton.java:74)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.loginInner(LoginCtrl.java:62)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.login(LoginCtrl.java:41)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (connect failed)
            java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
            java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
            java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
            java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
            com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
            com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
            com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:204)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:975)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:843)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:440)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
            org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
            org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
            org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)

...
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.<init>(DataSingleton.java:48)
            com.aldondy.boonder.bl.DataSingleton.instance(DataSingleton.java:74)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.loginInner(LoginCtrl.java:62)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.LoginCtrl.login(LoginCtrl.java:41)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            com.aldondy.boonder.web.controllers.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.76 logs.
```

Comment: also having the same issue, on centos 7.4.1708 and tmocat 7.0.76

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just also tracked down this issue.  My symptoms were the exact same as yours and I even tried the exact things you tried.  In summary my problem only occured because I was using tomcat on centos with SELinux.

Some folks helped me diagnose using the following commands to look at security events and why some actions were not permittted:

```
sudo ausearch -m avc
sudo grep "tcp_socket" /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why // translates log into some human readable reasons why the audit record was generated
```

I saw entries like:

> type=AVC msg=audit(1507861264.561:64750): avc:  denied  { name_connect
>   } for  pid=1326 comm="java" dest=3306
>   scontext=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0
>   tcontext=system_u:object_r:mysqld_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
>
> Was caused by:      Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.
>
> You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

And then found this article about tomcat and SELinux https://noobient.com/post/165972214381/selinux-woes-with-tomcat-on-centos-74

You can run the following command to see if tomcat is running in the tomcat_t security context.

```
$ps auxZ | grep tomcat
```

For the purposes of truly determining if my error was SELinux, I disabled SELinux

```
$ sestatus // shows: SELinux status:                 enabled
$ sudo vim /etc/selinux/config // set "SELINUX=disabled"
$ sudo shutdown -r now
$ sestatus // shows: SELinux status:                 disabled
```

restarted my machine and saw that tomcat was now making the outbound connection.

Great, now I at least know WHY that was happening.  Of course if you need SELinux, disabling it is NOT a solution.  Another workaround which is probably not a solution is to install tomcat without going through yum.  Yum will installed tomcat using the security context.

I think the course of action now is to modify the security context or set of rules governing tomcat to allow it to make outgoing connections.

Comment: Thank jbu ! That worked perfect for me. Such a relief after being stuck with this for so long... I disabled SELinux as you suggested and now SQL works ok. Now, I will start digging on SELinux configuration to see how I can get connectivity without disabling it completely. If you have any more tips, or find something related - please share the extra steps needed.

Comment: Bug is now completely resolved without the need to disable SELinux. In order to add tomcat to the policy use the following 2 commands:
`
ausearch -c 'java' --raw | audit2allow -M my-java
semodule -i my-java.pp
`
@jbu

Comment: this didn't solved for me , but what I had to do was to place the jdbc driver jar  inside of the tomcat's /lib directory and restart it

Comment: thanks for the hint by @jbu . Fixed the issue by 'setsebool -P tomcat_can_network_connect_db 1'

Comment: @gYanI This is me, Amir Forsati from his friends computer; My friend said, He will pay my uber if i solve this problem for him. Thanks you, You saved his life and my money!

Comment: good to hear and can understand why your friend agreed on terms :) , Me and my Devops team struggled a lot but I found the fix.

Comment: You're my favorite person right now... I had no inclination to check selinux. Now it's fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This command fixed my same permission problem:

```
setsebool -P tomcat_can_network_connect_db 1
```