# Java.net.SockerException Connect Failed - Permission Denied TOMCAT 7.0.76

Tags: java, tomcat, centos7

I am having difficulty to execute a website.

Following the tomcat log that is displaying the error:
Version of Tomcat: 7.0.76
CentOS 7.0

```
    $Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permissão negada (connect failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
```

[image]

Please, someone can help me? :)
Thx

Comment: The version of  Oracle JDK 7.0_80

Comment: So, you're having difficulties starting up Tomcat or accessing a page there? Can you give more details about how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Mick, then Tomcat starts normally. In the beginning, the default Tomcat page that you access through http: // localhost: 8080 appeared, so tomcat was installed correctly ...
After a development team started using tomcat and migrating a site that communicates with a database started giving this error.
I am not from the development area, I work only with infrastructure.
They tested by IDE pointing to the database server and ran the site normally and when running the system by the server gives that error.

What can it be?

Thank you.

Comment: Network firewalls (`iptables` in CentOS) are first that come to mind. Can you check that the app server has access to the database server?

Comment: The firewall is firewalld. I will check this! just a minute.

Comment: Mick, Firewalld does not blocking nothing. You have skype? Thanks.

Comment: You have a firewall at the Tomcat side that is prohibiting the outbound connection.

Comment: Hi EJP, How I can allow the outbound connection in firewalld? What is the command? Thanks!!!

Comment: `firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --get-all-rules` `ipv4 filter ouput 0 -p tcp -m tcp ACCEPT.` Is this?

Comment: If this is really a firewall problem, a better place to ask for help would https://serverfault.com

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689530/tomcat-hibernate-connection-to-mysql-fails-with-communications-link-failure

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the SELinux was involved. Had to enable the denied activity, this is how I did it:

```
grep postgres /var/log/audit/audit.log > ~/tomcat_w_postgres.log

audit2allow -i tomcat_w_postgres.log -M tomcat_w_postgres

semodule -i tomcat_w_postgres.pp
```